# GET https://localhost/api/list.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with angular, connecting mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, angular

Well I'm new for connecting mysql with php with a angular service and so facing these issues. 
Trying to connect mysql using php in angular.
In angular I have the service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Cityweather } from './cityweather';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CityweatherService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  baseUrl = 'https://localhost/api'; 
  cityweathers: Cityweather[];

getAll(): Observable<Cityweather[]> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/list.php`).pipe(
    map((res) => {
      this.cityweathers = res['data'];
      return this.cityweathers;
  }),catchError(this.handleError));
}

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  console.log(error);
  // return an observable with a user friendly message
  return throwError('Error! something went wrong.');
}

}
```

Here is the connection.php which I'm using to connect to mysql.

```
<?php
// db credentials
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'xyz');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

// Connect with the database.
function connect()
{
  $connect = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST ,DB_USER ,DB_PASS ,DB_NAME);

  if (mysqli_connect_errno($connect)) {
    die("Failed to connect:" . mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  mysqli_set_charset($connect, "utf8");

  return $connect;
}

$con = connect();
?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens if you visit the `api/list.php`  URL in your browser?, Also are you sure the configured your localhost corrrectly to run with `https` ?

Comment: I get the below error GET https://localhost/api/list.php net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Try it `http` instead of `https` because iám pretty sure you didn't install a (test) ssl certificate on your localhost to test.. Otherwise i have a feeling this error is more browser related.  Find if Google knows the [answer](https://www.google.com/search?q=net%3A%3AERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED) ..

Comment: `connection refused` means nobody is listening on port 443 on your box.  If it was a certificate issue, you would get a different error.